# Magic: The Gathering Arena - How to switch basic land art?

Tags: pc, magic-the-gathering-arena

Right now when you filter for lands to put in your deck you're presented with just the Rivals of Ixalan (RIX) lands.

Is there any way to use land arts from other sets?

Answer (score 3):

Right now in **Open Beta** there are ways but they might add an easier way in the future.

**Using Arena Interface:**

- When editing your deck write the land you want into the search bar (eg: Mountain)
- Then access the filters and click "RESET"
- You will be presented with every type of Mountain available in the standard format.
- You can then pick whatever land art you prefer from the mountains.

**Using a text editor:**

- First go the deck you want to edit and click **Export** (it copies the deck code to your clipboard)
- Open notpad or any other editor and paste the contents
- Choose the land you want to change and change it's set code and number. For example, if you want to change a mountain to the Dominaria land change "Mountain (RIX) 195" to "Mountain (DOM) 263"
- Copy the contents again and in the Decks page just import the deck

Answer (score 1):

An update added this as a basic feature. You are now able to select basic lands like any other card by simply clicking the lands filter in the deck builder.